# VDI Solution(s)

Tags: virtualization, vdi

I am currently in the planning stages of rolling out a VDI (Virtual Desktop) solution where i work as such i am looking for feed back on the different ways this can be done.

I have seen [VDI Comparison - VMWare View vs. XenDesktop vs. Sun VDI](https://serverfault.com/questions/57230/vdi-comparison-vmware-view-vs-xendesktop-vs-sun-vdi) and was hoping that someone has gone further on their VDI deployments, i am trying to mainly workout the information such as clients that could be provided per server or the server spec that is recommenced ect...

any help that you can provide would be greatly received :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We went the Xen Desktop route. 
We are running 3 physical hosts running Xen Server. Each has 2 Xeon quad core processors, and 24GB of Ram. This setup runs 12 servers (2 publishing applications to remote users) and 8 desktops with room to spare. Small environment, i know, but it can give you an idea of how it would scale.

Using Xen Desktop and Xen App we are able to utilize the Xen Receiver for client connections. This has been very easy to use, and allows for a great user experience, including with multimedia. There is, at times, some flicker with flash video, but that is usually solved by making it full screen.

Hope this assists in your search, albeit late.